# Why does my CURL connection hang?

Tags: php, curl

Accessing some URL's cause my CURL connection to hang. Any idea why?

```
$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $_GET['address'] );  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1)');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
$str = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Are you able to access the urls any other way? Have you tried running traceroutes to the target servers?

Comment: `CONNECTION_TIMEOUT 2` and `TIMEOUT 5` are quite limiting for a lot of sites. When we do connection to random sites in work we usually use TIMEOUT 30 seconds to cope with network and webserver lags.

Comment: Your CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT/CURLOPT_TIMEOUT values are way too low. Have you tried increasing them?

Comment: @spidEY & vyktor Yes, I tried to increase the time, but I'm still seeing issues.

Comment: @Ilion - I can access the URL directly, but that's it.

Comment: After looking at this some more, the issue could be with a class I'm passing `$str` into. However, If you guys have any other ideas, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @Paul Try adding a [`Connection: close`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.10) header to the request.